# Script to merge four access tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am attempting to write a script for access that will add only records that do not already exist from one table to the next, keep track of which records were not merged, and preserves relationships between the second table I'll be updating. I am unable to figure out how to, using VBA or SQL, insert data from a source table to a destination table that doesn't already exist in the destination table. 
Can anyone suggest a way for me to copy over data from `table A` to `table B`, when two of the rows fields don't already exist in `table B`? 
Ex. I have `table A` with four rows and `table B` with another four rows. I wish to copy over all data from `table A` where the value of fields `X` and `Y` don't already exist in any of `table B`'s `X` and `Y` fields.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tableB (columns)
SELECT [values]
FROM tableA AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS B
ON (A.X = B.X AND A.Y = B.Y)
WHERE B.X IS NULL
```

The outer join will include entries where there's no value for Table B, and the WHERE filters on only these rows

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I tried your suggestion, and it's saying "Duplicate output destination 'PID'". The field PID is a primary key field in both tables, and some of the primary keys are the same in both tables. How could I fix this error?

Comment: Is PID set to auto increment? If so you can leave it out of the insert statement. If not, the quick and dirty solution would be to use something like SELECT A.PID + 1000 to make sure there's no overlap. This isn't a long term solution though

Comment: It is set to auto increment in both tables, so I won't include it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the answer has worked for you, you can accept it which helps other users looking for similar answers (and improves my score)